# Как отследить изменения модели одним событиям в Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular4

Здравствуйте!

Как отследить изменения модели например в **input type="text"** не опускавшись до нативных событий **(click, change, blur, keyup)** и одним событиям: например - **ngChange** которое будет реагировать за любыми изменениями модели? Подобный функционал есть в **Vue.js** - **watch** и в **React** - **onChange**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать событие **ngModelChange**.

Официальная документация [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inside-ngmodel).

Пример [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchange?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

```
<select  (ngModelChange)="onSelection()"  [(ngModel)]="selectedNode" required >
  <option *ngFor="let node of tenant.nodes" [value]="node">{{node}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

В Angular конечно же есть такие возможности.
Например ngOnChanges или ngDoCheck.
Подробнее можно смотреть здесь https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks